# How to plot a network chart that is static and not dynamic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I've been playing around with network charts recently. I think I'm starting to understand this concept, but something is off here. My sample code is shown below.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\migration.csv")
df.head()

import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Country', target='Citizenship')

import pyvis
from pyvis.network import Network
net = Network(notebook=True)
net.from_nx(G)
net.show("example.html")
```

This works, sort of, but it's animated, and it keeps refreshing, over, and over, and over. Here's an image.

[image]

The data is sourced from here.

https://www.kaggle.com/timoboz/migration-nz

I think the image should be static, and not dynamic. Any thoughts on what could be wrong here?

Comment: to get data from kaggle we have to login and it may need to create account. Better put example data directly in code.

Comment: as I know NetworkX uses Matplotlib so it should have function to save plot in image `.png`, `.jpg`.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by saying "it's animated"?  Is the graph itself changing, and it's animating the changes?  Or is it the same graph, just being redrawn differently?

Comment: `plt.savefig("graph.png", format="PNG")` gives graph as image but it doesn't use `pyvis` so it may need something else to make it similar to version from `pyvis`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `net.toggle_physics(False)` right before `net.show("example.html")` stops the graph from shaking and gives the following static output:

[image]

More details can be found [here](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#visualization)